# Issue while hitting Post Method api in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to call an API in which I'm trying to send some parameters and array of images, but when I hit the API I get an error, `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfb47bab3e1e91166'`. I have checked through breakpoint it crashes on parameters, I'm confused why it is giving this error, my code for the API is this,

```
func addAPI()
{
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        /* "Authorization": "your_access_token",  in case you need authorization header */
        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    ]


    let parameters :[String: Any]  = ["name":productNameTxt.text!,
                                      "price":priceTxt.text!,
                                      "size": sizeTxt.text!,
                                      "weight":weightTxt.text!,
                                      "quality":qualityTxt.text!,
                                      "brand":brandTxt.text!,
                                      "shippingCost":shippingCostTxt.text!,
                                      "details":detailTxt.text!,
                                      "material_id":materialId,
                                      "material_type_id": subMaterialId,
                                      "maxQuantity":4]


    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            if let data = ((value) as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: key)

            }
        }

        for (index, image) in self.imageArray.enumerated() {
            multipartFormData.append(image.pngData()!, withName: "file", fileName: "image\(index).png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }
```

//            for i in 0..

```
    },
                     to: addProductUrl,method:HTTPMethod.post,
                     headers:headers, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                        switch encodingResult {
                        case .success(let upload, _, _):
                            upload
                                .validate()
                                .responseJSON { response in
                                    switch response.result {
                                    case .success(let value):
                                      //  compBlock(value as AnyObject,true)
                                        print("responseObject: \(value)")
                                    case .failure(let responseError):
                                        print("responseError: \(responseError)")
                                    }
                            }
                        case .failure(let encodingError):
                            print("encodingError: \(encodingError)")
                            let errorDesc = (encodingError as NSError).localizedDescription
                            //failure(errorDesc as NSString,false)
                        }
    })

}
```

What is this error for and how I can remove it?

Comment: try "maxQuantity":"4"

Comment: `((value) as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)`. You are assuming that all `value` can call the method `.data(using:)` which is a `String` method. But you have at least `"maxQuantity":4]`, and clearly, the "4" is not a String. It's an Int (and in Objective-C to be called like that, it's a NSNumber).

Comment: i have int and string both values in parameter how i can sent both of them? @Larme

Comment: still same issue. @BenRockey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here

```
if let data = ((value) as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
```

then any passed value have to be converted to **Data** and since you specify an integer ( `NSNumber` when wrapped inside json)    hence the crash so change **4** to **"4"** and

```
"material_id":"\(materialId)",
```

Comment: @JunaidKhan also `material_id":materialId`

Comment: but i have to send materialId in int data type to backend. @Sh_Khan

Comment: you can't send it like this try and see

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you follow like this:

```
 //[String:String] instead of [String : Any]
 let parameters :[String: String]  = ["name":productNameTxt.text!,
                                  "price":priceTxt.text!,
                                  "size": sizeTxt.text!,
                                  "weight":weightTxt.text!,
                                  "quality":qualityTxt.text!,
                                  "brand":brandTxt.text!,
                                  "shippingCost":shippingCostTxt.text!,
                                  "details":detailTxt.text!,
                                  "material_id":"\(materialId)",
                                  "material_type_id": subMaterialId,
                                  "maxQuantity":4]


multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
```